# Change Chrome homepage for multiple PC's

Tags: batch, google-chrome, homepage

In our business we have about 300 PC's. What I want to achieve is to change the homepage on all browsers (IE, Chrome and Firefox). The problem is that I can't find any way to set/change the homepage on Chrome for all computers at once.

IE can be configured through GPO and in Firefox I run a batch file that does that. How can I do this on Chrome without changing it manually on each PC?

Answer (score 1):

See Google's Help document [Set Chrome policies for devices](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en).  They provide Group Policy templates you can add on your Domain controller, so you can configure policies to set things like the home page.

I haven't found a updated document to confirm the current state, but in the past you needed to have the [Chrome for Business and Education](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/) installed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a place where Chrome configuration is stored: 
 http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory 
 
There you have file named Preferences - it's a JSON file - you can find there some properties for homepage and for example parameter which is responsible for loading homepage on startup:

```
"startup_urls": [ "http://google.pl/" ]
```